# Sending buffer to Arduino, corrupt data

Tags: serial-port, arduino, boost-asio

I'm using the Boost Librarys to communicate with a Arduno via the serial port. I have made communication class on both te PC and the Arduino. For now the Arduino just recieves the buffer and echo's it back.

The send and recieve functions are as follows:

```
void CommunicationModuleSerial::SendBuffer(char* Buffer, int Size){

    Serial.write((uint8_t*)Buffer, Size);
}

void CommunicationModuleSerial::RecieveBuffer(char *Buffer, int Size){

   for(int i=0;i <sizeof(Size); i++){
       Buffer[i] = Serial.read();
 };
```

And the functions are called in a Ardunio sketch (CM is the class instance):

```
CommunicationModuleSerial CM;
char Input[10]; 
char Output[10];


  while(1){

   if (Serial.available() == 10) {

     CM.RecieveBuffer(Input, 10);   
     CM.SendBuffer(Output, 10);
   };

   //delay(1000);
   Serial.flush();
};
```

On the PC side i use boost, the first problem is when i fill the buffers with a's and b's. The second buffer hold a's and b's, but should hold only b's.

```
    char InputBuffer[10];
char OutputBuffer[10];

for(unsigned int i=0; i < sizeof(InputBuffer); i++){
    InputBuffer[i] = 'a';
}

for(unsigned int i=0; i < sizeof(OutputBuffer); i++){
        OutputBuffer[i] = 'b';
}

cout << "inhoud after filling InputBuffer: " << InputBuffer << endl;
cout << "inhoud after filling OutputBuffer: " << OutputBuffer << endl;;
```

The output reads as follows: 
inhoud after filling InputBuffer: aaaaaaaaaa
inhoud after filling OutputBuffer: bbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaa

My first question is how can it be the Outputbuffer alsow contains a's?

Next there is a simple while loop that contain's a send and recieve function.

```
while(1){

    // Send buffer
    Serial.SendBuffer(InputBuffer, 10);

    // Recieve buffer       
    Serial.RecieveBuffer(OutputBuffer, 10);

    cout << "inhoud OutputBuffer: " << OutputBuffer << endl;;

}
```

The problem  is that the loop hangs after a couple of times after the send operation and that the output buffer also holds bbbbbbbb, which should have bin overwritten with a's.

The send and recieve operations on the PC side are as followed:

```
int CommunicationModuleSerial::SendBuffer(char* Buffer, int Size){

Buffer[Size+1] = '\0';

write(*Port,buffer(Buffer, Size));


return COMMSUCCES;
}

int CommunicationModuleSerial::RecieveBuffer(char *Buffer, int Size){


read(*Port,buffer(Buffer, Size));

return COMMSUCCES;
}
```

Can anyone help me with these problems? Many Thanks in advance.

Update:

Thanks to Matthias247 I have sovled some of the problems. Many Thanks Matthias247. I still have a data corruption problem. On the Ardunio side i take the recieved buffer and i send it back. but when i do that the first two characters have the right value(a), but the rest not. When i use a diffrent output buffer on the Adruino side and i send that back i get all te correct values.

Also the the loop seems to hang after a few send and recieves on the pc side. I think it blocks on the recieve function. Can anyone help me with these problems?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is how std::cout tries to print out your data:
It's excpecting a 0-terminated string. However your buffers `InputBuffer` and `OutputBuffer` are not 0-terminated. Therefore std::cout prints further (until it finds any other 0 or crashes due to a segmentation fault). Therefore your b's are printed after the a's.

If you really want to print only the content of the buffer use sth like his:

```
cout << "inhoud after filling InputBuffer: ";
for (int i = 0 ; i < sizeof(InputBuffer) ; i++) cout << InputBuffer[i] << " ";
cout << endl;
```

You have exactly the same problem in your while loop.

And your CommunicationModuleSerial::SendBuffer also contains a serious error:

```
Buffer[Size+1] = '\0';
```

You are trying to assing a value to an index (11) which is not valid --> This will normally also lead to a segfault/crash. In your lucky case this will write a 0 to the first position of OutputBuffer. You don't even the assignment here, the write function does not care about the 0 termination.

Alternatively you could use a 11 character array for both buffers, use the last character for 0 termination and send/receive only the first 10 bytes (as currently). This way directly assigning the buffers to cout will also work.

Upate: Some further bugs are here on the Arduino side:

```
void CommunicationModuleSerial::RecieveBuffer(char *Buffer, int Size) {
for(int i=0;i <sizeof(Size); i++){
   Buffer[i] = Serial.read();
 };
```

Here you are trying to read sizeof(int) bytes - therefore you are only reading 4 bytes (or maybe even 2 on Arduino) instead of 10. `i < Size` would be correct.

And additionally in your while loop:

```
if (Serial.available() == 10) {
 CM.RecieveBuffer(Input, 10);   
 CM.SendBuffer(Output, 10);
}
```

This will not work if the PC sends to packets at once and instead will block forever. You should better use `if (Serial.available() >= 10) {`

Comment: Thanks Matthias247 that expains a lot, still have some problems with data corruption. I have put these in the updated posed, do you know what the problem might be?